# Chrome - issue with "width: 0px"

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, width

It seems I am having a strange issue in Chrome, with "width: 0px".
I am setting the width to 0, in order to partially hide a link. On mouseover I am displaying the link, with a simple animation.
While Firefox and Opera behave nicely, in Chrome I see the link's text displayed, even though the width is set to **0**. (in IE and Safari I cannot test right now)

For your convenience, I added the code in a fiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaidoru/yNzSH/

QUESTION: How can I make Chrome display the same thing as Firefox, CSS only, if possible.

**NOTE: the menu should respect the CSS: "position: fixed; right: 0px".**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "cleaner" to hide the element rather than setting the width to 0px? using either display:none;

Comment: @DaveHogan — Then the slide animation wouldn't work.

Comment: I also have a padding on the right for each link, where an icon should be. For simplicity, I didn't add the images too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the width to 1px instead of 0px. It makes it so that the green background appears and when you hover over it it expands as expected. I also changed it to 1px in your jQuery.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/yNzSH/10/)

Comment: Thank you. This is much closer to the desired effect. I don't understand, however, why setting the width to 1px works, and setting it to 0px, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Set the links to be `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Thank helps, however, I set: "position: fixed; right: 0;", and there is a space on the right of the #menu, only displayed in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css overflow property

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` does not work for me, try `display:none`; javascript reads ok.